# PIServer client autologin

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

I've got a Raspberry PI 3B+ configured to diskless boot with the PIServer PXE system. I have created a user 'map7' and would like it to autologin my thin clients into the GUI as that user.

I've edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in the **chroot** section and also tried the **server** section and both attempts don't autologin at all. I've tried raspi-config -> boot options -> desktop autologin which sets it up for the 'pi' user then I changed it to 'map7' and still no joy.

The **chroot** section is the image on the server in which the thin clients mount and use as their root file system. This is in `/var/lib/piserver/os/<image name>`. The image name maybe *Raspbian-2018-11-13* in my example. I use the `chroot` command to enter into this directory and add my changes for the thin clients. I can add packages etc. The **server** section is the [Raspbian Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/) (which includes scripts for setting up a PIServer and I run in a VM) in which I'm booted into.

I do have the thin clients booting with different users, but I want one of those users to be automatically logged in. I'm using the thin clients as media centers with remotes so they won't have a keyboard to login with.

How do I get 'thin clients' which are linked to PIServer using the Raspbian Normal image to autologin?

**Update**

I've found that if I try and login really quick at the login screen on the thin client it rejects my username and password. I've tried many times so I know it's not me typing the password incorrect.

I started timing as soon as the dialog box appears, then I type my username and password and hit enter.

5 seconds after the login box appears fails.
10 seconds it accepts the password and continues on.

So there seems to be a timing issue here with thin clients and maybe setting up mount points before it can authorise itself.

**UPDATE**

Found that it isn't possible with write access to setup autologin for a PIServer thin client. It is however possible if you make it read only.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/piserver/issues/11

Comment: Don't the instructions at https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/set-up-piserver/ give you enough detail?

Comment: What is the *chroot section*? What is th *server section*?

Comment: Ingo: The chroot section is the image on the server in which the thin clients mount and use as their root file system. This is in /var/lib/piserver/os/<image name>. The image name maybe Raspbian-2018-11-13 in my example. I use the 'chroot' command to enter into this directory and add my changes for the thin clients. I can add packages etc. The server section is the Raspbian x86 PIServer VM in which I'm booted into.

Comment: Dougie: No those instructions don't include any detail about autologin. I've followed those instructions and I do have the thin clients booting with different users, but I want one of those users to be automatically logged in. I'm using the thin clients as media centers with remotes so they won't have a keyboard to login with.

Comment: Offering a bounty won't help if the question is unclear. "Raspbian x86 PIServer VM" - what is this supposed to mean - Raspbian only runs on an ARM SOC?

Comment: Do you want to autologin to the console or to the GUI Desktop? Please address me with @Ingo (you missed the `@`), otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Milliways There is a x86 version of Raspbian https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/. This version has been setup with scripts to help setup diskless booting of Raspberry PI's. I run this version of Raspbian (which is based on Debian Stretch x86) within VirtualBox as a Virtual Machine.

Comment: @Ingo The GUI Desktop

Comment: There is **NO** "Raspbian x86 PIServer VM" If you want to ask about  "Raspberry Pi Desktop" (which is **NOT** Raspbian) ask on a Debian site.

Comment: @Milliways This question is about the Raspbian ARM version in the chroot section so it should be here.

Comment: @Milliways thanks for the post.  I'm trying to achieve the same goals as you.  I've followed the github instructions but i still get the logon.  Hows did you solve this?

Comment: when i say logon, i meant i can get it to autologin.  Any tips appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at PiServer in detail, so don't know if this is possible, but have you tried the following changes (modified as needed for your chroot'ed config)? This is what raspi-config does, and looks like it should be capable of being performed in your environment.

```
SUDO_USER="autologin-username" # map7 in your case?
#(systemctl set-default graphical.target) The next line "simulates" this
ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target /lib/systemd/system/default.target
ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
cat > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf << EOF                                                                  
[Service]                                                                                                                             
ExecStart=                                                                                                                            
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin $SUDO_USER --noclear %I $TERM                                                                     
EOF                                                                                                                                   
sed /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf -i -e "s/^\(#\|\)autologin-user=.*/autologin-user=$SUDO_USER/"
if [ -e /etc/profile.d/raspi-config.sh ]; then
    rm -f /etc/profile.d/raspi-config.sh
    if [ -e /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/raspi-config-override.conf ]; then
      rm /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/raspi-config-override.conf
    fi
```

Comment: I just tried this and the thin client doesn't autologin to the GUI, it's still left at the login screen.

Comment: I get the error 'systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.server.d/autologin.conf:1] Invalid section header '[Service] art=/sbin/agetty --autologin map7 --noclear %I xterm'

Comment: I'm guessing you did, but can you confirm that you modified the commands to operate on your chrooted environment? Also, the lines [Service] and each line following it need to be on separate lines in the autologin.conf file. From the error, it looks as if they're all on one line?

Comment: Yes it was in the chroot area. I did notice that it was on one line and fixed that. The error went away but still doesn't auto login. I'm now thinking it's a timing issue. Please look at my update at the top.

Comment: Planning to set up my own test...stay tuned.

Comment: I have a testbed running now, which exhibits the same behavior as you're seeing. I've chased through several possibile fixes, without success. If this is a prevalent problem, the piserver folks will get it fix. Have you reported it to them?

One thing of note: The answer I provided above is not necessary. You can simply run raspi-config on the server in the chroot command window to modify the image. Nice!

Comment: I did find this issue https://github.com/raspberrypi/piserver/issues/11 it doesn't look like it's getting fixed. The only solution they have is to run it in read only.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I saw in the logs. I wonder if it's possible to combine the info from that thread and use an nfs-mounted /home directory to persist files. Probably doable, but a slightly complex setup and potentially fragile.